# Kubernetes pod fluentd forward to fluentd DaemonSet

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, daemonset

As we know we can deploy fluentd as DaemonSet in EKS

it can log all the stdout / stderr from the pod

however if a php application write a log into a file, the fluentd in DaemonSet will not catch the content of the file

how do we make it happen?

im thinking put another fluentd container into the pod, and then tail the log file, and then forward it to other fluentd  in DaemonSet

e.g

```
laravel.input.conf: |-
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 1s
      format_firstline /\[\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]/
      format1 /^\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] (?<environment>[^ ]*) (?<severity>[^ ]*): (?<message>.*)$/
      time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
      path /var/log/laravel.log
      pos_file /var/log/laravel.log.pos
      tag myapp.laravel
    </source>
```

is it possible

and how do make it happen?

Comment: What's preventing you from fixing the php application so that it just writes to stdout?

Comment: they using laravel, and required to change code to make it happen, but if developer dont wanna do that by some reason, i need to help them to do above things, i did once before, but forgot the step

Comment: Do you need Kubernetes Metadata for your PHP logs? If not then you can tail your PHP logs file using tail plug-in.

Comment: i need the metedata too, as what i did before is install a container inside the same pod to tail the log and together with kube metadata, then push to es

Answer (score -1):

Why not just write out to stdout or error and using fluentd:

```
<source>
    @type tail
    @id in_tail_containers_logs
    path /var/log/containers/*.log
    ....
</source>
```